# Layout of sum result in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, format

I am just wondering if its possible I have a result set where I am using a sum on one of the columns and passising the total into another column but it is coming up in each column not in the last column of the result set
So my query goes like this - (Select A,B,C, Sum(A) over() as Total)
My result set is -

```
      A   b    c        Total
      1   abs  efjne     10
      2   efa  fefme     10
      3   dvd  efnefn    10
      4   fhd  efmefe    10
```

But I am after the total to have only just one 10 in the bottom girght hand corner of the result set

Any help would be appreciated, I am using t-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using conditions:

```
select a, b, c,
       (case when row_number() over (order by A desc) = 1
             then sum(A) over ()
        end) as Total
from t;
```